# How to fit 3 equations in the page with number 2a, 2b and 2C?

Tags: equations, tabularx, labels, resize

I have the following issue. I am trying to fit 3 equations in one line with the label of 2a, 2b and 2c. Up to now (I am using tabularx)I am only able to get the 3 equations on the same line with numbers 2 ,3 and 4. Moreover, the numbers are positioned down the equations and not beside. I might also have to re size the equation. I tried in several ways but unfortunately it does not work.
Could you help me please?
Here the code, thanks in advance

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,titlepage]{book} 
\usepackage[paperwidth=165mm, paperheight=238mm, left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq, nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{showframe} 
\usepackage{cases}


\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{showframe} 
\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}
begin{equation}
\label{eq: time}
T_{m}^{v+1} - T_{m}^{v} 
\end{equation}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXX@{}} 
  \begin{equation}
  \eta_{em,str1} =  \frac { Q_{em,ideal,str1}} {Q_{em,str1}} 
    \label{eqn:1}
  \end{equation} &
  \begin{equation}
 \eta_{em,str2} =  \frac { Q_{em,ideal,str2}} {Q_{em,str2}}
    \label{eqn:2}
  \end{equation} &
  \begin{equation}
 \eta_{em,ctrl} =  \frac { Q_{em,ideal,ctrl}} {Q_{em,ctrl}}
    \label{eqn:3}
  \end{equation}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any particular reason to not using `subequation` from `amsmath`, and stacking them on top of each other?

Comment: Btw, you should change the variable descriptions, i.e. `em`, `str1`, `ideal` etc to `\mathrm{em}`, `\mathrm{str1}`, and so on to make the typography correct

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of mathrm, now they look better but I still have the same issue, they do not fit on the same line. I would like to see these simple equations on the same line that s why I do not use sub equation. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

The best solution is: don't do this ... equations become unreadable small:

[image]

Code:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq, nccmath}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq: time}
T_{m}^{v+1} - T_{m}^{v}
\end{equation}

\begin{subequations}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\tiny
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXX@{}}
  \begin{equation}
\eta_{em,str1} =  \frac { Q_{em,ideal,str1}} {Q_{em,str1}}
    \label{eqn:1}
  \end{equation} &
  \begin{equation}
\eta_{em,str2} =  \frac { Q_{em,ideal,str2}} {Q_{em,str2}}
    \label{eqn:2}
  \end{equation} &
  \begin{equation}
\eta_{em,ctrl} =  \frac { Q_{em,ideal,ctrl}} {Q_{em,ctrl}}
    \label{eqn:3}
  \end{equation}
\end{tabularx}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:** your equation is simple to wide to be fit in text with, so maybe is time to use some unconventional solutions:

- make indices shorter with aliases and in text give meaning of them
- broke indices into more lines
- ...

Last possibilities (with multi line indices) gives code below:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq, nccmath}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq: time}
T_{m}^{v+1} - T_{m}^{v}
\end{equation}

\begin{subequations}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
%\tiny
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXX@{}}
  \begin{equation}
\eta_{\substack{em,\\str1}} =  \frac {Q_{\substack{em,\\ ideal,\\str1}}}
                        {Q_{\substack{em,\\str1}}}
    \label{eqn:1}
  \end{equation} &
  \begin{equation}
\eta_{\substack{em,\\str2}} =  \frac {Q_{\substack{em,\\ ideal,\\str2}}}
                        {Q_{\substack{em,\\str2}}}
    \label{eqn:2}
  \end{equation} &
  \begin{equation}
\eta_{\substack{em,\\ctrl}} =  \frac {Q_{\substack{em,\\ ideal,\\ctrl}}}
                        {Q_{\substack{em,\\ctrl}}}
    \label{eqn:3}
  \end{equation}
\end{tabularx}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** 
As @clemens pointed in his comment, *the subscripts probably shouldn't be in math mode* (since each character aren't separate variable) *... They do seem to be text.* For converting them to text are more possibilities: use of `\text{...}` for upright shape, or `\textit{...}` for italic shape. For the first case the code of equations in `tabularx` is:

```
\begin{subequations}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXX}
  \begin{equation}
\eta_{\substack{\;\text{em},\\ \text{str1}}}
    = \frac{Q_{\substack{\text{em},\\ \text{ideal},\\ \text{str1}}}}
           {Q_{\substack{\text{em},\\ \text{str1}}}}
    \label{eqn:1}
  \end{equation} &
  \begin{equation}
\eta_{\substack{\;\text{em},\\ \text{str2}}}
    = \frac{Q_{\substack{\text{em},\\ \text{ideal},\\ \text{str2}}}}
           {Q_{\substack{\text{em},\\ \text{str2}}}}
    \label{eqn:2}
  \end{equation} &
  \begin{equation}
\eta_{\substack{\;\text{em},\\ \text{ctrl}}}
    = \frac{Q_{\substack{\text{em},\\ \text{ideal},\\ \text{ctrl}}}}
           {Q_{\substack{\text{em},\\ \text{ctrl}}}}
    \label{eqn:3}
  \end{equation}
\end{tabularx}
\end{subequations}
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: The subscripts probably shouldn't be in math mode… They do seem to be text.

Comment: Maybe, I left them as they were in given MWE. It is easy to add for example `_{\substack{\text{em},\\ \text{ideal},\\\text{str1}}}`.  Later evening I will upgrade my answer ....

Comment: *I* know that. :) But the OP maybe doesn't so I thought it might be worth to add a note to your answer

Answer (score 2):

Speaking for myself, I can't help but remark that typesetting the three sub-equations side by side in a row looks plain awful. Either the font size has to be shrunk so drastically that the equations become well-nigh unreadable, or you need to introduce so many line breaks in the subscript terms as to impair readability. Continuing to speak for myself, I'd also claim that if the equations are sufficiently important to be assigned individual equation numbers, it's a good idea to list them one per line. I thus suggest you use an `align` environment to display the three subequations.

Do note that it's not a good idea to display the subscript strings "em", "str1", "str2", "ideal", and "ctrl" as if they were formulas. Instead, use either `\mathit` ("math italics") or `\mathrm` ("math roman") letters for the subscript terms. Some people advocate the use of upright ("roman") letters, others say it's OK to use italic letters. Just be sure to choose one method or the other and to be consistent in its usage throughout the document. The code and screenshot shown below illustrate the "looks" that result from both methods.

Aside: Since you're passing the options `paperwidth=165mm` `paperheight=238mm` to the `geometry` package, it's mildly confusing to specify `a4paper` as a document class option -- I would drop the `a4paper` option.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=165mm, paperheight=238mm,
            left=2.5cm,right=2cm,vmargin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength\textwidth{8cm} % just for this example
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:time}
T_{m}^{v+1} - T_{m}^{v}
\end{equation}

\begin{subequations}
\noindent \texttt{\textbackslash mathit} for subscript terms:
\begin{align}
  \eta_{\mathit{em},\mathit{str}1} &=  
  \frac { Q_{\mathit{em},\mathit{ideal},\mathit{str}1}} {Q_{\mathit{em},\mathit{str}1}}
    \label{eqn:1}\\
 \eta_{\mathit{em},\mathit{str}2} &=  
 \frac { Q_{\mathit{em},\mathit{ideal},\mathit{str}2}} {Q_{\mathit{em},\mathit{str}2}}
    \label{eqn:2} \\
 \eta_{\mathit{em},\mathit{ctrl}} &=  
 \frac { Q_{\mathit{em},\mathit{ideal},\mathit{ctrl}}} {Q_{\mathit{em},\mathit{ctrl}}}
    \label{eqn:3}
\end{align}

\bigskip
\noindent \texttt{\textbackslash mathrm} for subscript terms:
\begin{align}
  \eta_{\mathrm{em},\mathrm{str}1} &=  
  \frac { Q_{\mathrm{em},\mathrm{ideal},\mathrm{str}1}} {Q_{\mathrm{em},\mathrm{str}1}}
    \label{eqn:1}\\
 \eta_{\mathrm{em},\mathrm{str}2} &=  
 \frac { Q_{\mathrm{em},\mathrm{ideal},\mathrm{str}2}} {Q_{\mathrm{em},\mathrm{str}2}}
    \label{eqn:2} \\
 \eta_{\mathrm{em},\mathrm{ctrl}} &=  
 \frac { Q_{\mathrm{em},\mathrm{ideal},\mathrm{ctrl}}} {Q_{\mathrm{em},\mathrm{ctrl}}}
    \label{eqn:3}
\end{align}

\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the first time I've seen a recommendation of `\textit` rather than `\mathit` (or `\mathrm`) in math mode. That also seems like it could be a problem if the chosen text font is significantly different from the math one.

Comment: @JAB - I guess we have no specific information from the OP about the text and math font families that he/she uses. Of course, if Computer/Latin Modern is in use, `\textit` and `\mathit` are essentially indistinguishable. If the text and math fonts did differ meaningfully, deciding whether `\textit` or `\mathit` (or `\textrm` or `\mathrm`...) was most appropriate would depend crucially on the intended appearance of the strings `ctrl`, `ideal`, `str1`, etc.

Comment: The use of `\text` is clearly wrong. But `\textit` seems bad as well, these are named indices and thus ought to be typeset upright to distinguish it from actual variable indices. So `\textup` or `\textnormal` might be a better choice. That is too long to write, so I tend to recommend egregs `\tsub` solution, which then used as `X\tsub{em}` or what ever.

Comment: @daleif - Thanks for these comments. I've updated the answer to show the looks resulting from both `\mathrm` and `\mathit`. My view is that as long one is consistent in one's notation and explains to the reader what the notational conventions are, either upright or italic letters can be appropriate.

Comment: @Mico That is why egregs `\tsub` is good, separation of the formation and the use